# Receiving syntax error when placing coffeescript at the end of ruby on rails view using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

I am working in Ruby on Rails

> (Ruby: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16],
>   Rails: Rails 5.1.4)

with haml as the view language. When I place a coffeescript block at the end of the view I receive an error:

> Showing
>   /Users/wayne.pfeffer/Projects/novu-admin/app/views/hermes/exports/show.html.haml
>   where line #51 raised:
>
> SyntaxError: [stdin]:21:78: unexpected identifier

Line 21 is empty.

Line 51: `:coffee`

If I comment out the entire coffescript, the view works. It's below a `:javascript` block if that matters.

My question: Why am I receiving the syntax error when the view code looks like any other view we've created?

Comment: might help if you show the code